# Load ASP.NET MVC Partial Views Dynamically Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a test link on the left side.  Each time user clicks the test link, I am adding a tab button and tab content (straight up HTML5 and CSS).  This is what it looks like:

[image]

### Controller Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MDMS_Web.Controllers
{
    public class MainViewController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /MainView/

        public ActionResult MainView(string name)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = name;

            return View();
        }

        //[ChildActionOnly]
        //public PartialViewResult MainContentPartial()
        //{
        //    return PartialView("~/Views/MainView/MainContentPartial.cshtml");
        //}

        public ActionResult GetView()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/MainView/MainContentPartial.cshtml");
        }

    }
}
```

### Partial View

```
<div id="MainContentBox" style="margin: 0em 0em;">
    <h2>Testing</h2>
</div>
```

### Main View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<main id="mainView">
    <div class="row" style="min-width: 100%; ">

        <div style="float: left; width: 20%; min-height: 870px; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left: -1em; overflow: hidden; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: lightgray; ">
            <div id="Test">
                <div class="row" style="background-color: #c2cbfb; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; ">
                    <p id="menuTitle" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 5px 0 5px 0; ">Test</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-wrapper">
                    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img class="icon" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; " src="Content/images/dashboard/CheckIcon.png" alt="Check icon" />
                        <a id="TestLink">Test Stuff</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="float: left; width: 80%; min-height: 870px; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left: 0em; overflow: hidden; ">
            <div id="MainContentBox" style="margin: 0em 0em;">
                <div id="tabs" class="tab">

                </div>

                <div id="content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="loading">

    </div>

</main>

@section scripts{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/MainView")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { MainView.initModule('@ViewBag.Name') });
    </script>
}
```

### JavaScript

```
function addTab(evt) {
    stateMap.tabIndex += 1;

    // add tab button
    console.log(evt);
    var tHtml = '<button id="tb' + stateMap.tabIndex + '" class="tablinks">' + "New Tab " + stateMap.tabIndex + '</button>';
    $("#tabs").append(tHtml);

    console.log("we have a new tab!");

    // add tab content section
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.setAttribute('id', 't' + stateMap.tabIndex);
    node.className = "tabContent";

    // load partial page place holder
    var contentPlaceHolder = document.createElement('div');
    contentPlaceHolder.setAttribute('id', 'c' + stateMap.tabIndex);
    node.appendChild(contentPlaceHolder);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(node);

    console.log("we have new content placeholder for partial view!");


 // HERE IS WHERE MY PROBLEM BEGINS !!!!!!
 // NOTHING I DO WILL LOAD MY PARTIAL PAGE !!!!


    //@{ Html.RenderPartial("MainContentPartial"); }
    //$("#c" + stateMap.tabIndex).load('@{ Html.RenderPartial("MainContentPartial"); }');
    //$("#c" + stateMap.tabIndex).load("GetView");
    $(function () {
        $("#c" + stateMap.tabIndex).load(
            '<%= Url.Action("GetView", "MainViewController") %>'
        );
    })
    //url: 'MainViewController/GetView',
    //$.ajax({
    //    url: 'GetView',
    //    dataType: 'html',
    //    success: function (data) {
    //        $("#c" + stateMap.tabIndex).html(data);
    //    }
    //});
}
```

### JavaScript initModule

```
var initModule = function (data) { 
    stateMap.currentSection = data;

    //Bind events
    $("#TestLink").on("click", function (event) {
        addTab(event);
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".tab").on("click", "button", function (event) {
            openTab(event);
        });
    });

};

return { initModule: initModule };
```

**My issue is with the last part of the JavaScript and probably the Controller.**  Can someone please tell me the correct way to load the partial view into my dynamically created tab content using JQuery?

Comment: Where are you calling the `addTab` method ?

Comment: Your code would be giving a 404 (Not Found) - its `Url.Action("GetView", "MainView")` , not `"MainViewController"`

Comment: I changed "MainViewController" to "MainView" and now I get this error:  GET http://localhost:51233/%3C%=   400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Are you really using aspx instead of razor? And from your edit, it looks like your script is in an external file which means that you need to use `$("#c" + stateMap.tabIndex).load('/MainView/GetView');`, (`Url.Action` is server side code and is not parsed in external js files)

Comment: But a better option is to use `Url.Action()` in the main view to generate the url and pass it to the script

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I'm using razor.  But I've tried every solution I could find, so I might be getting my syntax mixed.

Comment: If its razor, then its `var url = '@Url.Action("GetView", "MainView")';` to generate the url (or just `var url = '@Url.Action("GetView")';` if the method is in the same controller

Comment: Also you don't need the enclosing `$(function () {` around your `.load()` method

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason to add `id` attributes to your elements (and if you think you need them for another reason then you probably doing something else wrong). And you just calling the same view each time you add a tab which does not really make sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I'm still just a little confused.  Should I use the variable url in the $.ajax() call?  Everything else gives me a 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164301/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-patricia).

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I will eventually be calling different views.  Right now, I'm just trying to get one to display.

Comment: where is your openTab method defined ?

Comment: If you want to load partial view content in the tab click then may be you can go for an ajax call and the corresponding html result you can bind it to the required div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load Partial View dynamically using Jquery in following way

```
$(document).on("click", "#TestLink", function () {
        var url = "/MainView/GetView";
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
 });
```

Here URL is the URL of action which will return PartialView.

Comment: The url and the .load syntax is confusing to me.  So, I want to be sure I understand.  For `var url = '@Url.Action("GetView", "MainView")';` is the first parameter the PartialViewResult method name and the second parameter the ActionResult method name?  And for var `url = "/MainView/GetView";` the MainView is the ActionResult method name in the controller and the GetView is the PartialViewResult method name in the controller?

Comment: Yes, you are right, here `MainView` is the Controller name and `GetView` is its action which is returning PartialView. If you are writing this js function in your .cshtml page you can use `var url='@Url.Action("GetView", "MainView")'` but if it is in separate file you have to use `'/MainView/GetView'`