# ASP.NET MVC dynamically add existing (stand-alone) view as a Partial

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, razor-pages

**Does anyone know how to load an existing (stand-alone) view as a partial view?** I found a tutorial at this link [(gillesleblanc.wordpress.com/…)](https://gillesleblanc.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/asp-net-mvc-dynamically-adding-an-existing-view-as-a-partial-view-to-a-parent/) but it looks more complicated than I think I need.

I'm able to load a partial view using the following syntax:

```
$('#elementName').load('controllerPartialViewMethod/controllerActionViewMethod');
```

The above syntax is supposed to be the same as the following syntax, though I've not been successful using it.  But that is not my current issue, just a statement of observation.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("controllerActionViewMethod", "controllerPartialViewMethod")';
```

**My problem is that I want to use an existing (stand-alone) view as a partial view.**

I created a controllerPartialViewMethod for the existing (stand-alone) view to return the view but, of course, the JavaScript is not hooked up.

All of our existing (stand-alone) views are called using Razor syntax like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "controllerActionViewMethod", "controller");
```

I have found this [Redirecting to another page in ASP.NET MVC using JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8148657/1735836)
 that looks promising.  I'll be looking at that and perhaps creating a container that can be replaced.

If anyone knows how to do this, please help.

### Existing Report View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Usage Report";
}
<main id="usageData">
    .
    .
    .
    <div id="loading">

    </div>
</main>

@section scripts{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/UsageReport")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { UsageReport.initModule() });
    </script>
}
```

### Main View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main View";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<main id="mainView">

    <div class="row" style="min-width: 100%; ">

        <div style="float: left; width: 20%; min-height: 870px; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left: -1em; overflow: hidden; border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: lightgray; ">

            <div id="EnergyManagement">

                <div class="row" style="background-color: #c2cbfb; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; ">
                    <p id="menuTitle" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 5px 0 5px 0; ">Energy Managemement - Reports</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-wrapper">
                    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img class="icon" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; " src="Content/images/dashboard/GraphIcon.png" alt="Graph icon" />
                        <a id="AggregatedUsageLink">Aggregated Usage</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-wrapper">
                    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img class="icon" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; " src="Content/images/dashboard/GraphIcon.png" alt="Graph icon" />
                        <a id="EUILink">EUI</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-wrapper">
                    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img class="icon" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; " src="Content/images/dashboard/GraphIcon.png" alt="Graph icon" />
                        <a id="CustomQueryLink">Custom Query</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-wrapper">
                    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img class="icon" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; " src="Content/images/dashboard/ReportIcon.png" alt="Report icon" />
                        <a id="QRURLink">QRUR</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="row content-wrapper">
                    <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <img class="icon" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; " src="Content/images/dashboard/ReportIcon.png" alt="Report icon" />
                        <a id="EnergyProjectsLink">Energy Projects</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="float: left; width: 80%; min-height: 870px; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-left: 0em; overflow: hidden; ">

            <div id="MainContentBox" style="margin: 0em 0em;">
                <div id="tabs" class="tab">

                </div>

                <div id="content">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="loading">

    </div>

</main>

@section scripts{

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App/MainView")

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () { MainView.initModule('@ViewBag.Name') });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Sorry !  What is your exact problem ? This is a very broad statement **"I've not been successful at using the following syntax:"** Can you be more specific on what the expected behavior and where you are stuck at ?

Comment: Sorry, my problem is that I want to use an existing (stand-alone) view as a partial view.  I've reworked my question.

Comment: So you want to include a partial view in your main view ? How are you trying that ? Are you using `Html.Partial("YourPartialViewName")` ?

Comment: No, In the JavaScript, I am using $('#elementName').load('controllerPartialViewMethod/controllerActionViewMethod'); that would be the same as var url = '@Url.Action("controllerPartialViewMethod", "controllerActionViewMethod")' to generate the url, or just var url = '@Url.Action("controllerPartialViewMethod")' if the method is in the same controller.  this is all working perfectly for a partial view.  I had a previous question for loading partial views here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48552760/1735836

Comment: But now, I want to load an existing view as a partial view.  I can load it just fine but the external JavaScript used to interact with the view is not loaded.

Comment: check your browser dev tools->console and see whether you have any script errors. Also check the network tab and see whether that specific call is made. You also need to share the relevant part of the code in the question so others can spot any potential issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164579/discussion-between-patricia-and-shyju).